# Im having problems with returning a dataframe object in R from a function that removes outliers

Tags: r, outliers

I am trying to create a function that returns the remainder of a dataframe with the outlier removed for a specific column but the dataframe object that is returned is always empty no matter what column i use.

```
remove_outlier = function(dataframe,column){
  average = mean(dataframe[[column]])
  std = sd(dataframe[[column]])
  cutoff = 3 * std
  lower = average - cutoff
  upper = average + cutoff
  print(lower)
  new = dataframe[dataframe[[column]] > lower & dataframe[[column]] < lower]

  return(new)

}

testing = remove_outlier(BostonHousing,'age')

head(testing)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
 new = dataframe[dataframe[[column]] > lower & dataframe[[column]] < lower]
```

Since there's no equal sign there's no possible way to be greater than a value and lower but not equal at the same time. This line is incorrect, I suspect you intended to have upper there instead.

```
new = dataframe[dataframe[[column]] > lower & dataframe[[column]] < upper,]
```

EDIT: add a comma, thanks to u/maydin for the catch.

Comment: Thanks just changed it but now im greeted with another error.                                        `Error in .data.frame (dataframe, dataframe[[column]] > lower & dataframe[[column]] <  : 
  undefined columns selected`

Comment: Try calling with age without quotes.

Comment: Object 'age' not found :(

Comment: I think you need to put a comma after uppet in @Reeza ‘s answer

Comment: @maydin wow thank you!! I am a python user so still thinking in pandas mode. Thanks to you both